# VBA array Vlookup

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I wanted to create a vlookup straight from VBA editor (not referred to cells).
I've tried a 2D array but it doesn't work.

```
Sub vl()
    Dim typ(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

    typ(1, 1) = A
    typ(2, 1) = B
    typ(3, 1) = C
    typ(4, 1) = D
    typ(5, 1) = E
    typ(1, 2) = 50
    typ(2, 2) = 40
    typ(3, 2) = 30
    typ(4, 2) = 20
    typ(5, 2) = 10

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("A", typ, 2, 0)
End Sub
```

I was hoping to get 50.

I know this can be done using a cell range but was hoping to do it straight in VBA Editor.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example why you should always use `Option Explicit`. Your code works, but because you did not have `Option Explicit`, the VBEditor thinks that `A` is a variable and not a `String`. Thus, it does not give anything on the MessageBox.

This works as expected:

```
Option Explicit

Sub vl()
    Dim typ(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

    typ(1, 1) = "A"
    typ(2, 1) = "B"
    typ(3, 1) = "C"
    typ(4, 1) = "D"
    typ(5, 1) = "E"
    typ(1, 2) = 50
    typ(2, 2) = 40
    typ(3, 2) = 30
    typ(4, 2) = 20
    typ(5, 2) = 10
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("A", typ, 2, 0)

End Sub
```

[MSDN Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)

Comment: Thank you very much, will have to look into Option Explicit further, very much appreciated.